# How to navigate from popoverpresentation view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a screen with a navigation controller and it has a button on the nav bar which displays a table (from another view controller) to select things from using pop over presentation, now on clicking any of those items i want to open another view controller a different screen.

BUT if i use        `navigationController?.pushViewController(tab, animated: true)`
  the new view controller is displayed within that small pop view itself

and if i use 
`navigationController?.presentViewController(tab, animated: true)`
 the navigation bar isn't there on that screen and i cannot go back to the previous screen. How to do it in such a way that i can go back to the screen which first displayed the pop Up list.

Comment: Do you use a storyboard, or just code?

Comment: code mainly @Sweeper

Comment: So do you have segues between the popover controller and the VC that shows it?

Comment: `  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        
        
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vm") as! vmViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(tab, animated: true)
        }  ` 
 this is how i present it, navigate from one view to another it works fine on the rest but only on the popover it isnt happening , probably because the popover has its own view controller and its just directly showing that

Comment: Come on, it's 2016 now. use unwind segues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Storyboard, it's really easy to do. If you're not, then you *should*. It's very good to use a Storyboard.

Let's call your view controllers these names:

- The view controller that can show the popover is called `SourceVC`
- The popover controller is called `PopoverVC`
- The view controller to show when the user selects something from the table view is called `NewVC`

Add a show segue connecting your `SourceVC` to your `NewVC`. Give the segue an identifier.

Add an unwind segue that unwinds from `PopoverVC` to `SourceVC`. First, add these methods in your `SourceVC`:

```
func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let vc = segue.sourceViewController as? PopoverVC {
        // get the thing that the user selected and store it somewhere
        // perform a segue that shows NewVC
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? NewVC {
        // pass the thing that the user selected to the NewVC
    }
}
```

Then, select the `PopoverVC` and control drag it to the "Exit" thingy in `SourceVC`. And select "unwind:". Give this unwind segue an identifier as well.

When the user selects a row in the table view, just perform the unwind segue and store the thing that the user selected in a class-level variable so that you can pass it to `SourceVC`.

Comment: the contents of the popovervs will be in the popovervc so if i add the above code to source vc how can i perform a segue to show newvc from sourcevc since popovervc is the vc that has the popped over data  in list(table) form

Comment: See the comment `// get the thing that the user selected and store it somewhere`? When a user selects a row, you store the thing that the user has selected in a variable in `PopoverVC`. Let's call it `userSelectedThing`. You just need to store the `vc.userSelectedThing` in a variable in `SourceVC`. Let's call it `userSelectedThing` as well. In `prepareForSegue`, pass `self.userSelectedThing` to `NewVC`. Yeah I know it's complicated. After all, you are passing info across 3 VCs.

Comment: i used the unwind segue but strangely the moment i navigate to newVC from the unwind i navigate (pushed) for an instant to newVC and then it pushes me back to the sourceVC @Sweeper

Comment: @KyleFernandes Hmm... That is weird indeed. Did you connect the segues correctly? Remember to connect the *view controllers*, not the particular views in the view controller. You should try to solve it yourself first. If you *really* can't solve it, post another question with your code and what you have tried.

Comment: i ran the function with a timer after 0.01 seconds and then this problem was fixed @Sweeper